# Google Analytics 'Send' Method Firing, 'Set' method does not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, angular-ui-router

I am trying to configure google analytics in my angular app, and I have found that when using the 'Send' method I can see the tracking pixel in my network tab, yet I cannot see the pixels firing when using the 'Set' method. I am not seeing an error of any kind and the google troubleshooting docs don't provide much insight, any help is greatly appreciated. Here is a sample of two pixels I have:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '/about');
```

this works fine, however:

```
 ga('set', 'page', {
    title: 'About',
    page: '/myinfo/about'
 });
```

Does not fire at all. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Solution:

```
        ga('set', {
          title: 'About Page',
          page: '/pages/about.html'
        });
        ga('send', 'pageview');
      }
```

Sends the proper payload. Thanks to Philip Walton for the troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong, it should be:

```
ga('set', {
  title: 'About',
  page: '/myinfo/about'
});
```

Here is the documentation on the set command:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference#set

And here's a guide that explains how to get and set data on a tracker object:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/accessing-trackers